# Copy file in home directory during Homebrew formula install

Tags: macos, homebrew, ruby

Is it possible to create files outside of `/usr/local/Cellar` during a Homebrew formula installation?

Here is my code:

```ruby
def install           
    cmd = "whoami; cd /Users/hughcrt; pwd; mkdir test"
    value = `#{cmd}`
    print value
end
```

And when I do `brew install --build-from-source my-formula` I get:

```
mkdir: test: Operation not permitted
hughcrt
/Users/hughcrt
```

It don't understand why I can't create a file as the user in the script is `hughcrt` and I'm in the right directory

Comment: Do you want to create “outside of /usr/local/Cellar” or specifically home directory? Home directory is a restricted location while other directories should work. For home directory try giving Terminal (and perhaps brew) full disk access if you haven’t. See [How to Fix “Operation not permitted” Error in Terminal for Mac OS](https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/)